# laravel $request is undefined in production, locally it works

Tags: php, laravel, request

I had some strange issue with Laravel and Request:

In my Controller i had in index:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request, $id) {
   try {
        $from = Carbon::parse($request->query->get('from', '1970-01-01'));
        $till = Carbon::parse($request->query->get('till', Carbon::now()))->endOfDay();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Invalid time range or data',
        ], 400);
    } 
}
```

which works on my local machine.
But when i deploy it to production and dump($e) in catch (\Exception $e), i get the following exception:

> $message: "Undefined variable: request"

so I changed to

```
use App\Api1\Requests\TicketRequest;

public function index(TicketRequest $request, $id)
```

which works locally and on production server.

the TicketRequest.php just extends the Request:

```
class TicketRequest extends Request
```

Can anyone tell me, why $request is undefined on production, but not locally?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you need import `request`in your class `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Regardless of the class, $request would never be undefined here, you're not looking at the right spot.

Comment: `$message: "Undefined variable: request"` -- where is this $message..?

Comment: @BagusTesa - i had to dump($e) in production to get this message.

Comment: @Devon but it was. With this above mentioned change it works..

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos yes, i used it correctly. otherwise it would not have worked on development also

Comment: $request is still defined, it's an argument to the method, it can't be undefined in index().  I'm not saying you didn't have the error, but you're not posting the code relevant to the error.  Show a backtrace.

Comment: try in you server production run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Devon i updated description $request ist undefined in $from = Carbon::parse($request->query->get('from', '1970-01-01'));

Comment: Still doesn't work, $request literally cannot be undefined in this code block/scope.  It's a function parameter.  Show the backtrace from the error

Comment: put in you `carbon` `\Carbon::now()))->endOfDay()`

Comment: I did not get more than: 

 arguments: {
        $level: 8
        $message: "Undefined variable: request"
        $file: "/var/app/current/app/Api1/Controllers/TicketController.php"
        $line: 56
        $context: array:2 [ …2]

and line: 56 is  $from = Carbon::

Comment: how you send data on this method cant put you ajax??

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos i tested it with postman. its an api-endpoint.

Comment: my question is not HOW I should refactor it, so that it works, because I already did that. My question is more why its not working on production but on my local server i dont get any error, etc.

Comment: as Devon has pointed out, this is not the code throwing that error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request, $id) {
try {
    $from = \Carbon::parse($request->query->get('from', '1970-01-01'));
    $till = \Carbon::parse($request->query->get('till', \Carbon::now()))->endOfDay();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'error' => 'Invalid time range or data',
    ], 400);
}
```

}

Comment: i have litterally the same code in another Controller and it works:     public function index(ProductSaleRequest $request, $resellerId)
    {

        try {
            $from = Carbon::parse($request->query->get('from', '1970-01-01'));
            $till = Carbon::parse($request->query->get('till', Carbon::now()))->endOfDay();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Invalid time range or data',
            ], 400);
        }

so i dont think Carbon has anything todo with it.

Comment: you try run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`??

Comment: yes did that. as i commented above its more a question of why it does not work on production server but locally it does... composer.lock is the same on both. also server is dockerized so there shouldn't be any problems..